# How can I use Laravel's Storage to download files from a remote SFTP server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filesystem, laravel-storage

I'm writing an **artisan command** in **Laravel 5.5**. There are files in an **AWS EC2** instance and **all within the same folder**, my command needs to **download all those files** into a local storage/folder. 
*I went through the Laravel's documentation but couldn't find helpful info*. I have added a disk into my filesystem config file for my local storage/folder access, as well as a disk for my AWS SFTP server.
*Previously I've been doing this using the phpseclib but would like to move on using Laravel in Laravel way.* 
I've tried the following:

```
Storage::disk('aws')->get('path/filename.ext');
```

which throws the following exceptions:

```
In FilesystemAdapter.php line 109:
path/filename.ext
```

and

```
In Filesystem.php line 388:
 File not found at path: path/filename.ext
```

but I can see the file is there and my program can download it, and actually all of them using phpseclib.

and also tried the following **which returns an empty array**:

```
Storage::disk('aws')->files('folder-name');
```

and aws is the disk I've defined in the filesystem config file as follows:

```
'aws' => [
    'driver' = 'ftp',
    'host' = '12.123.123.12',
    'username' = 'myusername',
    'password' = 'mypassword'
 ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to generate link for those files ? have you linked your storage folder by php artisan storage:link?

Comment: I don't want to generate links I just need to download them all to the local storage into a specific folder, and the point is that I want to download all the files without knowing their names. I'm not sure about storage:link as I didn't see that in laravel's documentation about filesystems, would you please elaborate on that a little more? thanks!

Comment: oh if you want to download all files why dont u use putty or filezilla ?

Comment: @fahim152 you should read my question more carefully. I'm creating Artisan Command and files need to be downloaded and procesed by the command.